# Merge Sentinel images in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, sentinel

I have two Sentinel scenes that I would like to stich together. I successfully tried the QGIS merge tool. However the seams are very visible and the data ranges also do not seem to be correct.
What can I do to improve the result?

So far I did every band seperatley (e.g merge band 2 from image 1 with band 2 from image 2).

[image: here you can see the result]

Comment: Did you check the `Output data type` during the execution of the `Merge` tool?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with int16 and float 32 and Ulnt16

Comment: Can you provide test data? You say data ranges also do not "seem" to be correct - did you test to see if this indeed is the case? Did you try creating a virtual raster to see if the result is the same? And - just to exclude that: "the seams are very visible..." - are you sure you only see the resulting layer, not by chance any of the initial layers above the result somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two sentinel images will not stitch together perfectly. I assume that they are two images taken on different days, with different atmospheric conditions, different solar angle and different incidence angle. All of these things affect the image pixel values, so if they are all different then the two images will be different. One way to try and normalize this is to conduct an atmospheric correction first but this will not completely solve it.

Instead, consider getting lots of images that overlap and then mosaic them together using the mean statistic. This will help eradicate the seams. If you only have 2 images, as long as they overlap, you can stitch them using the average values between the two, but the more images you have, the better

Comment: To add to this excellent answer: what kind of mosaiking is advisable also is very dependent on what your goal is and what you want to do with the images afterwards.